# Change of affiliation after acceptance of a paper?

Tags: publications, authorship, affiliation

I will change my affiliation from University X to University Y in mid February, and I have got a paper accepted just before I move. The proofs will be sent back to the journal just a week before I change my affiliation.

Is it valid to use my new affiliation in the paper? This would be useful as it will count towards my publications in my new institution.

I have already signed a contract and will receive my new email address soon, however, my start date in my new affiliation is just a week after I submit the final version of the accepted paper.

Comment: Is the rule literally "if our affiliation is on the paper, then it counts"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different journals may have different rules, however, in general:

Affiliations indicate *where the work was done* (to be precise, where a (co-)author has been working while doing the work presented in the paper).

If you change institutes *while working on a paper* (including writing up and revising) you should enter both affiliations. When you are affiliated to multiple institutes while working on a paper (simultaneously), add both as well.

However, in a case like yours, assuming that the paper is now accepted (no more revisions), only the old affiliation should be added (unless your journal of choice suggests something else). No work has been done while you are working in the new position.

Comment: "Affiliations indicate where the work was done", do you have a reference for this? That is an interesting point I was not aware of. Some of my works have taken so long (I work on theoretical topics) that I have completed them in two institutions, but I only use the current one.

Comment: @mover I can't give you a proper reference, just a few links to guidelines, for example elsevier: https://www.elsevier.com/__data/promis_misc/RESINV_GfA.pdf or JNeurosci: https://www.jneurosci.org/content/information-authors You can sure find more examples.

Comment: Back when I was still moving around between institutions, my affiliation at the top of the paper would be where the experimental work was done, but the journals I published in would allow a footnote on the first page with my 'Current affiliation' listed there. I didn't count editing time.

Comment: The rule that "affiliations indicate where the work is done" is specific to some fields.  In pure mathematics, affiliations indicate where to find the author.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question depends on your field.

In some fields, affiliation indicates where you did the work.  In some fields, affiliation indicates where to find you (as of the time the paper was published).  There is probably some correlation to how much research actually depends on resources (e.g. lab space) provided by your institution.

Find some papers by people whom you know moved, and see what they did.