# Is it appropriate to change authors' affliation at the final stage of proof reading?

Tags: publications, affiliation

Suppose that you are the first-author of a paper that was accepted in a journal. During proof-reading, the corresponding author (the supervisor in this case) wants to change the affiliation of the authors. I know that it is possible to leave a comment to the journal in this regard as one can't directly make the changes when revising the proof, but I am asking, is that a common thing to happen?

Comment: Affiliation of authors (no matter they have been changed or otherwise) have nothing to do with the order of their names. Your supervisor's reasoning is quite weird, by the way!

Comment: @User. That's true.. matter of fact, he changed the order of authors during submission and we signed an agreement on that and now during the proof reading, he is asking me to change our affliation. It is bothering me but I can't do anything about it..

Comment: @User Why are you talking about the order of names? I'm not seeing any mention of order. If the department actually has closed (these things do happen) why would it be weird to change the affiliation? Why would that be unprofessional?

Comment: @BryanKrause, I am not sure whether the thing about the department is true or not, but even if it was true, according to the second answer it is true that some journals have a clear policy that affliation should be where the majority of the work is done, so I do think that changing the affliation at proof reading is not professional cause at that stage no further work would be done.

Comment: @JaafarMehrez Just changing the department isn't much of a change. If a department is absorbed into others or split into two, the work is done at both the old name and the new name because they are just different names for the same place. Normally these changes are things that make "news" locally, can you not see any announcements or website changes that match the change?

Comment: @BryanKrause. I still don't know what is the new affliation, I was just informed that it will be changed with no further details of the new one.

Comment: Have you asked?

Comment: @BryanKrause. Of course I did, and I didn't get a reply yet. The proof was ready for review for over a week though.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. An affiliation is a way to find an author. If the author's department has been absorbed into another, or has changed its name, it is clearly appropriate to change that on the publication. What would be the problem in that?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth. My question was simply 'is it common to change the affliation at the last stage of the publication process'. Whether or not affliation is a way to find an author could be a seperate question that I might ask. Eventually, I would like to mention that after discussion, the corresponding author decided not to change the affliation.

Comment: I don’t understand this question at all. You’re the first author and your supervisor is co-author; and now your supervisor is telling you that your affiliation will be changed because your department has closed? How could your own department close without you knowing it if you work there?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet. Thanks for your comment, If you read my question carefully, I mentioned 'claiming that the department has been closed' actually it was not closed. The point of the question is whether changing the affliation at proof-reading stage is a common thing or not regardless of the reason.

Comment: @JaafarMehrez Still makes no sense to me. If they’re your supervisor, they are presumably at the same department as you… so they’re claiming that their own (and your) department has closed, even though it hasn’t? That just seems like such a bizarre thing to happen that whether it’s common to change the affiliation in proofreading is the least of your worries. At worst, it may be fraud and actually illegal, if the place they’re now claiming affiliation with is somewhere they’ve never been affiliated with.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, you look like you are going in one-way with your thinking here. Nobody is claiming to be affiliated somewhere it doesn't exist. As I mentioned in previous comments I was not fully aware and wasn't informed of much details. Just today we were informed of the details and the case turned to be similar to what was described in Bryan Krause comment, it is still the same department but split into two now. I think I will update my question so nobody would get confused again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not common, but it's surely because the production stage of a journal article lasts for a short time (days) compared to the time when authors are at an institution (years), so statistically it's unlikely to happen.

There's nothing wrong with making this change and you can certainly ask.

Comment: Another reason why this is not common is because people may prefer to give the affiliation valid when the work was actually done. So the affiliation would not change in the paper even if it does not reflect the current state. See for example https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/161866/change-of-affiliation-after-acceptance-of-a-paper and other related questions on Academia SE.

Comment: And I would think that changes in affiliation during the proof stage rather  reflect changes during the entire submission process which is much longer.

Comment: @Snijderfrey. I agree on that, thanks for the further clarification.

Comment: The claim about the production stage of a journal article is very field-dependent. In pure math, for example, the production stage routinely lasts many months.

Comment: @GregMartin Why does it take so long?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- It shouldn't.. Production is a quick thing (unless you count the point where you send proofs to the authors and they take a long time to return them). Really no excuses for taking that long. If it really does take this long (i.e. Greg Martin and I are thinking of the same thing), then mathematicians should demand more from their publishers.

Answer (score 14):

Personally, I would add a footnote for "current affiliation" rather than change the existing affiliation.

Otherwise, I agree with Tom's [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/208929/33210) and the good points he raises.
He notes that

> Moreover, some (or even most) journals have the policy that in the final proofreading stage, only issues that were introduced during the publishing process (e.g., due to typesetting by the journal) will be fixed. The proofreading stage is to ensure that everything appears as the authors originally intended it, not to enable the authors to change their minds.

Ostensibly, listing your "current affiliation" as a footnote at this point would help readers find you, the author (although, in practice, ORCIDs, the internet, lessen the importance of up-to-date affiliations in journal articles).

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the journal, it may not be appropriate.

Some journals have a policy that the [affiliation should be where the majority of the work was done](https://www.springer.com/us/editorial-policies/authorship-principles#toc-49266:%7E:text=The%20primary%20affiliation%20for%20each%20author%20should%20be%20the%20institution%20where%20the%20majority%20of%20their%20work%20was%20done.). The request may go against such a policy.

Moreover, some (or even most) journals have the policy that in the final proofreading stage, only issues that were introduced during the publishing process (e.g., due to typesetting by the journal) will be fixed. The proofreading stage is to ensure that everything appears as the authors originally intended it, not to enable the authors to change their minds.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer, I have checked the journal and they are clear in their policy that "the affliation should be where the majority of the work was done"

Comment: @JaafarMehrez but this doesn't change, right? You are saying that the departments have simply changed name or been merged, so using "newName" is correct, since "oldName" just doesn't exist any more.